# synchronous multiple socket client clarification

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcp

I am going to create multiple synchronous clients . I need some explanation about below code.
When i am creating a socket like below and call connect what is happening at network level.

I believe when we create a socket and call connect, a TCP/IP connection a tunnel made between client socket and server socket.

Once this sender(socket) connect with server ,that client & server will have a unique tunnel between them.
if i create another client it will have another unique tunnel between them.

In case if we got an error, that the client is not connected, always we should reconnect using  existing socket(sender) then we will access the same data/connection that we had.
And we should not create a new socket then we will have a new tunnel and we will lost the previous connection and data.

```
Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
sender.Connect(remoteEndpoint)
```

Please clarify if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call tunnel is really called a connection. Broken connections cannot be revived. Data loss is to be expected.

When you reuse an existing socket object to connect again you are creating a new connection. Reusing socket objects is not recommended (by me) because it is confusing.

Note, that TCP does not know what a socket is. The spec does not contain that word. Sockets are OS-level things.

Comment: i have few questions.                                                               1.We should try to reconnect to socket only if its failed at initial stage (just after creating socket object)                   2.I am creating separate socket object to serve different requests using different threads at client side . Then how server knows to which client it should send the data . because all client has same endpoints.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by (1). Regarding (2): Just keep a reference to the appropriate socket object and send and receive on it. The OS takes care of the rest.

Comment: one more question , So my (2) point is correct , i should create new socket for every request.

Comment: I don't know what a request means for you. You are talking in terms that I do not understand. You need to think of what the receiver of your communication knows and doesn't know.

Comment: Ok. please forget request. i am calling above mentioned code through different threads same time . i just want to know is it serve my purpose or not because i dont want to use locks or something to  synchronous.

Comment: It does not make sense to send on the same socket concurrently. The same for receives. The order of the data that is being transmitted is undefined in that case.

Comment: you mean, i cannot create several sockets client using above code and called them concurrently.

Comment: I did not say anything like that. Ask a new question. This one is done.